# How to limit Jenkins concurrent multibranch pipeline builds across branches?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anybody have an idea how to limit concurrent builds with a declarative pipeline set up in a multibranch job across branches?

Anytime we set an agent for a stage, a new executor will be allocated. This leads to deadlocks e.g. when you have builds triggered concurrently for as many branches as you have executors. Not setting an agent leads to the stage chosing an executor randomly, which isn't acceptable as certain stages need to run on certain agents...

The classic approaches don't work:

- Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin doesn't work with multibranch
- Setting `properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])` just limits concurrency per branch
- the `lock` step needs `agent none` in the pipeline root to prevent allocating executors, but this hinders our global `post` block to execute suff as it needs an agent and apparently one cannot set an agent for the post block

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit old and I'm not sure that the solution existed at the time, but if you set an agent on each stage, then it should not deadlock unless you have a dependency on another build that uses an agent.  Doing the below part will also execute the post block on the same node as the agent specified in the respective stage.
I've also added another pipeline post section at the end that you might need if you have to run the post block for the entire pipeline and need to have it run on the same agent used in a previous stage.  Hope this helps!

```
def agentNameStage2 = null
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Stage 1") {
            agent { label "somelabel" }
            steps {
                println getContext(hudson.model.Node)
            }
        }
        stage("Stage 2") {
            agent { label "anotherlabel" }
            steps {
                script {
                    def agentStage2 = getContext(hudson.model.Node)
                    println agentStage2

                    // Either use this hack or add whitelist hudson.model.Node getNodeName and use agentStage2.nodeName
                    //agentNameStage2 = agentStage2.nodeName // <-- Best method that needs whitelisting or to run as trusted
                    agentNameStage2 = agentStage2.toString().replaceAll('.*?\\[', '').replaceAll('\\]$', '')
                }
            }
            post {
                always {
                    // Running on an agent with "anotherlabel"
                   println getContext(hudson.model.Node)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            script {
                if(agentNameStage2) {
                    // Note this doesn't guarantee the same workspace as was used in the above Stage 2 section
                    node (agentNameStage2) {
                        println "Pipeline post is running on: " + getContext(hudson.model.Node)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Handle else case
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```